# Weakly sequentially compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness

From Peter Lax Functional analysis page 104:

> Show that a weakly sequentially compact set is bounded.
>
> **Definition.** A subset $C$ of a Banach space $X$ is called weakly sequentially compact
>   if any sequence of points in $C$ has a subsequence weakly convergent to a point of $C$.

Comment: I did not down vote but perhaps you might want to show some of your thoughts.

Comment: What do you mean by *weakly* sequential compact? Is it in $\Bbb R^n$ or in any metric space?

Comment: @Berci: Sequentially compact in the weak topology on $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is the following result:

> If $X$ is a normed space, and $\{x_n\}\subset X$ a sequence which converges weakly to $X$, then $\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\lVert x_n\rVert<\infty$.

It's a consequence of Baire's categories theorem applied to $X^*$, the topological dual of $X$.

We show that an unbounded set cannot be weakly compact. If $S$ is not bounded, let $\{x_n\}\subset S$ such that $\lVert x_n\rVert\geqslant n$. If $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, then for each $k$, $\lVert x_{n_k}\rVert\geqslant n_k$. In particular, $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is not bounded hence cannot be weakly convergent.